# Show that an odd number of a, b, and c satisfy $abc\equiv 1\pmod3$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, integers

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$ with $abc\equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Show that an odd number of a, b, and c satisfy this.

I've been thinking about it for a while but I still don't really understand where you would even start trying to prove this.

Comment: What do you mean by "an odd number of $a, b$ and $c$"?

Comment: What about I choose 3a,1b,1c, then 3abc is obviously 0 modulo 3 ?

Comment: Try $a=b=c=7$. $7^3 = 343 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$